# React Child component has undefined props.style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, inline-styles

I'm quite new to React. I want to create custom component that has several custom component inside it. Below is the code

```
const { item, to, onClick, width, style, ...otherProps } = props;
const h = width ? (width*IMAGE_RATIO)+'px' : 'auto';
const w = width ? width+'px' : 'auto';
<StackView
  style={{ width: w, ...style }}
  {...otherProps}
>
  <Container
    to={to}
    onClick={onClick}
    item={item}
    style={{ width: w, height: h }}
  />
  <ClickableText
    to={to}
    onClick={onClick}
    typography={typography.t15}
    color={color.red}
    activeColor={color.redDark}
    style={{ lineHeight: '12px' }}
  >
    {item.title}
  </ClickableText>
</StackView>
```

Inside the `Container` component and `ClickableText` component `props.style` got `undefined` tried to Google this problem but find nothing. Can somebody help me? thanks

**EDIT:**

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7047558/michael-ingga-gunawan) answer was spotted on. The problem is in my `StackView` component, I override children style while cloning them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's something wrong with the parent of `Container` and `ClickableText` component.

Please check the parent component `StackView`. If you override the children style, then that's the root problem of this mess.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

In case your component is not a Stateless Functional Component then you need to access the property by using `this.props.style`.

More on the component types here:
https://tylermcginnis.com/functional-components-vs-stateless-functional-components-vs-stateless-components-630fdfd90c9c

Comment: it's stateless component, all of them